# Want to Connect and disconnect with SIP Server using IOS 5.0

Tags: objective-c, ios5, sip, voip

I need to create an IOS application which has two buttons.

1. Connect
2. DisConnect

When user press connect button, it will allow user to connect with SIP server. (Asterik server) and when user press disconnect button, It simply get disconnected.

Have already gone through SIPHONE and its documentation, but giving error while making setup environment.